# Why is Params::Validate callback failing for anonymous function reference?

Tags: perl, anonymous-function

I am using [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Params::Validate) for validation, but at the callbacks section instead of defining the direct anonymous function, if I try giving the reference to that anonymous function it is directly jumping to the error logging area without printing the message inside the block (in case of passing correct value).

```
use Params::Validate qw(:all);
our $attributeCallback = sub {
    my $parameter = shift;
    $parameter =~ m/^\w+$/i ;
};

sub getSingleValue {
    eval { 
        my ($domainName, $attribute) = validate_pos( @_,
            { 
                type => SCALAR, 
                callbacks => {
                    'Domain name validation failed' => &$attributeCallback
                } 
            },
            { 
                type => SCALAR, 
                callbacks => {
                    'Attribute name validation failed' => sub { 
                        $_[0] =~ m/[\w.-]+$/i } 
                } 
            }
        );
        print "domain name is $domainName and attribute is $attribute";
        1;
    } 
        or do { 
        # catch 
        # Error Logging Area
    };
}
```

The actual error logged is something like  **"Undefined subroutine"** ...

Can anyone tell why is this happening so?

Comment: Your error would have been immediately visible if you had indented your code for human reading.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: how so?  The error is a misunderstanding that has nothing to do with indentation.

Comment: @ysth I find that the closer obscure little extra symbols are to the right margin (or wrapping around in twisted ways) the harder it is to even realize they are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's failing is because you are *calling* the subroutine reference and therefore using its return value, rather than passing the actual reference. Instead of using

```
&$attributeCallback
```

Use

```
$attributeCallback
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{ type => SCALAR, callbacks =>{'Domain name validation failed' => &$attributeCallback } }
```

`$attributeCallback` is already a code reference. I think you just want to say

```
=> $attributeCallback
```

instead of

```
=> &$attributeCallback
```

`&$attributeCallback` will call the function and is like saying

```
callbacks => {'Domain name validation failed' => 1 }
```